# Couldn't resolve host 'magento-community' error when installing Magento modules

Tags: magento

I tried to install the Module Creator by using `magento-community/Netz98_ModuleCreator` and I get the `Couldn't resolve host 'magento-community'` error.

I then used a [website](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) to download the extension and install it that way, and I get this error for this file `Netz98_ModuleCreator-1.0.0.tgz`.

> CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
>   Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
>   Invalid stability  Invalid channel URL
>   Empty authors section
>   Empty package contents section

Please help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting from Magento 1.5.0 you should use Magento Connect 2.0 extension key.

The developer of this extension created it compatible with Magento 1.3 only. You can download the extension package (*.tgz archive*), extract it and manualy put files in your Magento instance. Use `package.xml` to determine the file location.

Comment: Worked for 1.9.2.4, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Magento Module creator instllation instructions:

1) Login in to admin panel of magento

2) Go to System->Magento Connect->Magento Connect Mmanager

3) Go to Settings->Preferred State:->change stable to beta

4) Go to Extensions->Install New Extensions->use this key: - http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Netz98_ModuleCreator->click install->click ready to install

5) After successfull installation  go to your favourate file manager
go to path: app/code/core/mage/captcha/model/observer.php

and change

```
public function checkUserLoginBackend($observer)
{
$formId = 'backend_login';
        $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
        $loginParams = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        $login = array_key_exists('username', $loginParams) ? $loginParams['username'] : null;
        if ($captchaModel->isRequired($login)) {
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString(Mage::app()->getRequest(), $formId))) {
                $captchaModel->logAttempt($login);
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
            }
        }
        $captchaModel->logAttempt($login);
        return $this;
    }
```

TO

```
public function checkUserLoginBackend($observer)
    {
        $formId = 'backend_login';
        $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);

        $login = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('username');
        if ($captchaModel->isRequired($login)) {
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString(Mage::app()->getRequest(), $formId))) {
                $captchaModel->logAttempt($login);
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
            }
        }
        $captchaModel->logAttempt($login);
        return $this;
    }
```

6) If you are using linux/unix

Go to terminal->go to magento project folder->type chmod 777 -R /var/www/your-project-folder/

7) open you url in browser and add /moduleCreator after it

8) Done. You should be able to create module now.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Resolving this issue is very simple but getting to this point sometimes take time. That's why I'm providing here a simple solution so that it can work for the community.

If you want to install an extension using connect manager e.g. `"community/Test_Extension"`.

You'll have to write it like this: `http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Test_Extension`

But when you'll try installing using this key `community/Test_Extension`, it'll give you couldn't resolve host name issues.